# Directory permissions vs file permssions

Tags: permissions, directory, group

If I have two users called `john` and `sally`. Both are part of the `users` group. `john` creates a directory with permissions `775`. `sally` then puts a file there with `644` permissions.

Even though the file obviously has no group write privileges. Can `john` then modify/delete that file in the directory he owns but the file he does not own?

Comment: I have problem with your subject: "Directory permissions vs file permssions", Directory is a file too  in UNIX world. but regural file differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He can delete the file because unlinking depends on the directory's permissions, not the files. In this way, he can modify it since he can remove and replace it in the directory.

Comment: So the file would then be owned by john? When you say modify would that be a standard by applications (such as vi) to read, remove, and/or replace the file with the new one? Would that work in the same way as moving the file?

Comment: Yes, `vi` would support replacing the file with `:w!`.

Comment: And moving the file?

Comment: @gareth The same as deleting it.  Moving it just changes the source and destiantion directories.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, deleting a file doesn't actually modify the file, it modifies the directory and john has permission to do so.

The way to prevent this behavior is to set the `sticky bit` on the directory.  That is how /tmp allows everyone to write to it, but only the owners (or root) to delete things from it.

```
chmod +t directory
```

That will turn the sticky bit on.