# provide read, write, execute permission but can't be deleted by others

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, rm

Is it possible for a user to create a folder with read, write, execute permission for all users in the system, but the other users can't delete the folder?

Answer (score 5):

yes - the privilege for *deletion* belongs to the **parent directory**.

If you give permissions to write new files (or directories) in a given directory, those can be deleted by other users unless you use the "t-bit" feature (supported on most Unix-like systems).

Further reading:

- [I need to make a file undeleteable, but allow it to be modifiable and renameable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241405/i-need-to-make-a-file-undeleteable-but-allow-it-to-be-modifiable-and-renameable/241407#241407)
- [Directory permissions vs file permssions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94436/directory-permissions-vs-file-permssions/94452#94452)

Comment: BTW, do I need `chmod o+t` or `chmod +t` is enough?

Comment: Just the latter (`chmod +t`) should work for you.